# data type error while saving file to csv in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am simply trying to save data to a csv file in python using numpy.

This is what I am doing:

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', array, delimiter=',', fmt='%.4f')
```

however I am getting a following error

```
Mismatch between array dtype ('<U1') and format specifier ('%.4f')
```

what is this dtype and what does it mean?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tell us about your array.  The important stuff like its dtype and shape.

Answer (score 0):

The [`dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) of an np.array is its data type. In this case, `'<U1'` stands for unsigned integer data of width 1 byte, aka an `unsigned char` in c-style languages. This being integral, it is incompatible with the `'%.4f'` [format specifier](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html). Instead, use something like `'%u'`.

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', array, delimiter=',', fmt='%u')
```

If you really want your data formatted as floating point values in your csv, you can [cast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) the array to float like so:

```
np.savetxt('data.csv', array.astype(float), delimiter=',', fmt='%.4f')
```